# ¿Se puede lanzar un activity con un tabMenu y que no sea la principal?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Estoy tratando de crear una app android que contenga un login y si este es satisfactorio, que lance un nuevo activity con un tabMenu para poder avanzar entre el perfil, actividades y eventos.

El problema que tengo actualmente es que cuando creo mi adaptador android-studio devuelve un null pointer

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.citysportgym/com.example.citysportgym.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
```

He creado un adaptador personalizado:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter

class MyAdapter (fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
    private val fragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentList[position]
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }
}
```

Una clase singleton ya que estoy usando android volley para conectar mi app a mysql remota

```
import android.app.Application
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

/**
 * Created by Belal on 5/16/2017.
 */
class VolleySingleton : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
    }

    val requestQueue: RequestQueue? = null
        get() {
            if (field == null) {
                return Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
            }
            return field
        }

    fun <T> addToRequestQueue(request: Request<T>) {
        request.tag = TAG
        requestQueue?.add(request)
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = VolleySingleton::class.java.simpleName
        @get:Synchronized var instance: VolleySingleton? = null
            private set
    }
}
```

mediante un objeto, establezco la URL de conexión:

```
object EndPoint {
    private val URL_ROOT = "http://192.168.1.112:8080/webservices/index.php"
    val URL = URL_ROOT
}
```

Y en mi Main Activity, capturo el botón de login de esta, y hago un listener para llamar a la función de login que esta usa método de Volley y parámetros de mi objeto:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
            login(editTextEmail!!.getText().toString(),editTextPassword!!.getText().toString())
        }
    }

    // function login
    private fun login(email:String, password:String) {
        //creating volley string request
        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, EndPoint.URL,
            Response.Listener<String> { response ->

                try {
                    Log.i("eee", response)
                    //init profile activity if not have error
                    val myIntent = Intent(this, ProfileActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(myIntent)
                } catch (e: JSONException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            },

            object : Response.ErrorListener {
                override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError) {
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            })

        {
            @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>()
                params.put("email", email)
                params.put("password", password)
                return params
            }
        }
        //adding request to queue
        VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
    }
```

El login me está funcionando correctamente, llego a mi endpoint perfectamente, pero cuando inicio mi segundo activity, me devuelve el error mencionado, en esta línea, de mi segundo activity:

```
pager.adapter = MyAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
```

El segundo activity contiene:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.example.citysportgym.Adapter.MyAdapter
import com.example.citysportgym.databinding.ActivityProfileBinding
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator

class ProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var tabTitle = arrayOf("Perfil", "Actividades", "Membresia")

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityProfileBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        var pager = findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.viewPager2)
        var tabLayout = findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.profileLayout)
        pager.adapter = MyAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)

        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, pager) { tab, position ->
            tab.text = tabTitle[position]
        }.attach()

        binding = ActivityProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_profile)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal, la verdad es que soy novato con Android.

Gracias por leerme, la ayuda y un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todo lo que hiciste esta bien, lo que está mal es la interpretación de la duda que tienes. Si se pueden lanzar actividades de cualquier parte, lo que sucede aquí es que dicha actividad, la del perfil, es la del error.

Ahí claramente lo menciona en el error de la consola, intentas poner el adaptador en una pager que es nulo.

Si estas utilizando ViewBinding, porque lo tienes declarado tu variable, inicializala y de ahi obtener la referencia de tus vistas, asi el pager no será nulo, puesto que lo obtendrás de tu layout.

```
binding = ProfileActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
binding.viewPager2.adapter = MyAdapter(supportFragmentManager, lifecycle)
```